# Who has authority when it comes to texts?

Tags: discussion

If I found a mistake in a text that you valued very highly and had learned at the feet of a Buddhist master, how would you respond if I said it needed correcting? A real life example is the [Vajrasattva Mantra](http://www.westernbuddhistreview.com/vol5/). In my article I  showed that the commonly taught mantra is garbled and can easily be rectified, mainly by realigning word-breaks. I've also discovered a grammatical mistake in Conze's Sanskrit version of the [Heart Sutra](http://ocbs.org/ojs/index.php/jocbs/article/view/104). I have a third example of a grammatical mistake in a popular text in development that I don't want to announce just yet. But I am interested in how other people respond to these kinds of dilemmas.

Would you:

> a. adopt the revised version on the basis that the text was corrupt and has now been corrected?
>
> b. follow what you were taught, even if it is apparently wrong, because tradition is important?
>
> c. some other course of action?

If you chose to adopt a corrected version, how would you raise this with the person who had taught you the text?

Answer (score 3):

I'm posting this as an answer because it's too long for a comment, unfortunately it won't answer your question.

The "Buddhism.SE" site is one site among many within 'the stack exchange network'.

- Many things are specific to this site and **not shared** with other SE sites

  - The subject (i.e. Buddhism)
  - The site-specific policies (which we discuss on this meta-site)
  - The users (many users here are only users on this site and not familiar with other SE sites)
- Some of the things on this site **are shared** with other SE sites

  - Software (site layout)
  - High-level policies (e.g. "prefer Q&A to comments" and "foster a community of regular users" and "make the internet a better place")
  - Governance (e.g. each site has its own community of users, and a meta-site for formulating site-specific policies)

The main site is for asking questions about Buddhism:

- Theory
- Doctrine
- Practice
- History
- Culture
- ...

This meta-site is for discussing the main site:

- Policies e.g. [Moderation policies for Questions](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1558/254)
- Specific question (e.g. how to improve a specific question which was asked on the main site)

---

And now to your question:

- Your question doesn't quite belong here on meta; because it's not asking a question about the main site. If you wanted to make it a question about the main site you could do that:

  > Can I criticize texts which other people reference in their answers? If so what guidelines can I follow to avoid causing unwanted social friction here?
- Your question doesn't quite belong on the main site either. If you read the second half of the current [Moderation policies for Questions](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1558/254), one of the very few types of question which we think we're unable or unwilling to answer are questions which are polls of all the users.

  So, for example a question like to following would be off-topic:

  > Why are you reading this site?

  If it's a question which every user can answer, and where every answer is equally valid and there can be no "best answer", then it's probably not a good question for this site (because the SE sites' implementation of voting, for example, is to try to identify a "best answer" to each question).

  In general any question with the word "you" or "your" in it is suspect. For example [this question](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/10719/254) was closed as off-topic because it was asking "you" to answer questions about "you".

---

If you want to ask this question on the main site, can I ask or suggest that you try to reframe it?

For example (and I have to guess because I don't know why you were asking the above question) maybe you could reframe this question as,

> I have a problem '*X*' related to (the study or culture or practice of) Buddhism. Can you recommend one or more solutions?

Comment: There's also the ["what's meta"](http://buddhism.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta) page, which might be a useful read

Comment: OK Sorry. I wasn't aware I was on the meta site. But now it has an "answer" and I cannot delete it.