# Types of Questions and answers which are allowed

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

Is this a site for asking questions about the traditions of Buddhism and for finding out what the beliefs of Buddhists are. Or is it to ask questions about those beliefs i.e. if a belief seems a logical contradiction for someone, they ask how it can be, and some user answers using his Buddhist knowledge how it is possible, almost like a teacher would. Or is it both or neither?

Basically would it be reasonable for someone to ask the question "How can buddhists believe there is no self and yet also believe that the self is reborn at death?" and have it answered, maybe referencing sutras, like "Because there is a continuum not a fixed atman, +surangama highlights that the seeing nature is immutable therefore its destruction is impossible, so rebirth is certainty"

I have just read the other similar questions, which don't quite address this but are in the same area. (Is this question off-topic?)

Comment: I'm not sure I understood this question of yours: because you already answered more than a dozen questions on the main site, so haven't you seen what kinds of questions are asked there? Let me know if my answer below doesn't answer your question.

Comment: I realise now that you had already provided Moderation Policies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a site for asking questions about almost anything related to Buddhism: mostly doctrine probably, also practice and ethics, and some questions about culture.

It has elementary questions (from non-Buddhists), and more specific questions (from Buddhist practitioners and scholars).

It supports (at least in theory) all sects or schools of Buddhism, so if you want to ask a question and get an answer from the perspective of a specific school, mention the school in question or use an appropriate 'tag' (without which the question might attract answers from several schools).

The question, "How can buddhists believe there is no self and yet also believe that the self is reborn at death?", is a question about Buddhist doctrine: and therefore it's on-topic. A more precise/specific/expert question might get a more precise/specific/expert answer. There have been questions about rebirth before (currently 98 questions with the [rebirth](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rebirth) tag): can you avoid re-asking a question? In general we don't want to copy-and-paste and answers, so ideally try to make a new question specific enough that existing answers (to existing questions) don't answer the new question.

Perhaps you're familiar with other StackExchange sites. This site has slightly unusual [Moderation policies for Questions](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1572/254).