# Few Schools Represented

Tags: discussion, specific-question, specific-answer

This is stemming from [this question](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/19586/does-the-doctrine-of-no-soul-mean-there-is-nothing-permanent-to-continue) but it is part which has not been [addressed in so far](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2054/reopening-question-on-no-soul). So creating a thread for this specific part. Should a question should be put on hold thus blocking all other viewpoints and option when there is a answer from one or a limited number of schools. If one answer comes up I believe the playing field should be level so other schools / traditions can also represent their view.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Fairness and Equability to All Users](http://meta.buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/1805/254)

Comment: To be fair and equitable you either everyone should be able to have a response or no one at all. Not just one person! It is simply not Fair and Equitable when there is only one answer from one user!

Answer (score 1):

**If one answer comes up I believe the playing field should be level so other schools / traditions can also represent their view.**

I'm not sure I agree that's always the most important consideration.

I think the most important thing is that this is a Q+A site, whose topics (pages) consist of:

- a question
- one or more on-topic answers.

This site is (already) unusually permissive about how clear/unclear a question may be, even so occasionally a question crosses a line and is put on hold.
In this case the original question was "do you agree with me?" -- I sympathise with Lanka's finding that unclear and suggesting it should be replaced by a more-specific question.
Apart from its being unclear, "Do you agree with me" is phrased as a "polling question" (even if it wasn't meant that way), which is [one of the few reasons for moderating a question](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1572/254).

If the question isn't sufficiently clear (or "good") to begin with, then I see no benefit in the question's accumulating lots of answers.

Anyway, I voted to reopen the question: and in case it matters, I did that not for the sake of "fairness between schools" (i.e. in order to give every "school" an opportunity to post an answer to an unclear question), but because you edited the question to make it sufficiently clear (and because three users voted to reopen it, and the OP agreed with the edited version of the question).

Reasons for asking for clear questions include:

- To benefit the OP
- To benefit future readers of the site
- To minimize hostile disagreements between users (IMO arguments may occur if people haven't agreed on what they're talking about, and are therefore each arguing on different subjects)

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with participation from other schools.

A user had answered the question before a moderator (me) viewed and closed the question.

The question was closed due to being a statement and not asking an actual question.

---

As the question has now been edited and contains actual questions it can be reopened.
But before that, @Suminda as you are the editor, please make sure that the new questions are not *duplicates* of already existing questions.

When you have confirmed that the question can be reopened.

Comment: What I am saying is when one use gets and answer stub in before a Mod can do something. You should only sparingly close / hold things. The wording and presentation is diffrent from other similar questions as per this: https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/11/16/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/

Comment: Additionally there seam to be https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/06/10/improved-question-merging/ has a merging facility if you were to use it. This means there will be no dangling answer stubs for dupes. (Additional information only not related to above.)

Comment: Also there are 3 reopen votes.

Comment: Hello Suminda. Did you confirm the new questions are not duplicates?

Comment: @SumindaSirinathS.Dharmasena I reopened the question: after you edited it to turn it into a question, and the OP approved your edit. I guess it's probably a duplicate of something but it's not clear exactly what it's a duplicate of. I posted an answer, with references to many possibly-related topics.

Comment: Thank you. This was that was needed in the 1st place. Also note the person who posted does not have English as the 1st language. Hence he should have not been able to edit it and kept it open since there was an answer already, instead of putting it on hold, the better solution would be edit and help the user. Also it would have been more fair on the language barrier. Also fair that no one user gets special treatment.