# Post comments to help improve answers?

Tags: discussion, answers, comments, specific-answer

We have [liberal policies about accepting questions](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1558/254) (of any quality) ... but what about answers?

I noticed that Hugh was posting comments [in this topic](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/19695/254) -- and I was wondering whether I can recommend posting that kind of comments, as a way to improve the quality of answers?

Answer (score 2):

I think they're good comments: and, I commend the desire or attempt to improve the quality of answers; and I wouldn't mind seeing more participation (from Hugh or others) like that.

---

Beware that sometimes comments can be done badly, for example:

- "You're wrong!"
- "Your whole school of Buddhism is wrong!"

Two of the things I like about *these* specific comments of Hugh's:

- They're specific (about what's wrong) and prescriptive (about how to improve it)
- They're posted to benefit the OP, to try to ensure that answers fully address the OP's question.

---

Apart from benefiting the OP, it's also proper to post a comment if *you* don't understand the answer:

- "I didn't understand *this bit* of your answer, could you clarify that?"
- "Could you post a reference, where I might read more about what you wrote?"

If you think that an answer should be better, it's also proper to try to a post a better answer.

---

The one slight criticism that I have of Hugh's comments is that they impute a motive, e.g.:

> *you* care more about making sure that Buddhism is compatible with science instead of answering OP's doubts

I don't mind writing "you" conventionally, but [I avoid writing "you"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I-message) when I'm writing criticism.