# Should this "polling" question be closed?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

This topic on the main site, [Studying and practicing Buddhism](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/23629/254), which asks ...

> What is the most important thing, truth, lesson, you have learned so far?
>   And what would be the thing you most desire to learn?

... is a "polling question" as described in the [Moderation policies for Questions](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1558/254) ...

> 2. **"Polling questions"** which only ask "What's your experience?"
>
>    For example, [this
>      question](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/8763/254) was closed by
>      yuttadhammo and it's a type of question which he regularly closes. The
>      question asked this, after describing an experience,
>
>    > Has anyone ever experienced anyone like this off or even on (!) the mat? It was most striking...
>
>    I gave the following comment as an explanation for closing this
>      question:
>
>    > I think a problem with a question that is phrased like, "Has anyone ever experienced anyone like this?" is that it could attract an
>    >     unlimited number of people each answering "Yes, me!". Each new answer
>    >     would be a bit new (different from previous answers) and as valid as
>    >     any previous answer. There's no obvious way to select any best answer
>    >     to that question, no way for any answer to finish answering or to
>    >     provide a complete answer to the question. And it doesn't seem to
>    >     describe any practical problem you have, so there's no way for anyone
>    >     to help to answer/fix that problem.
>    >
>    > [Crab bucket's question](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/8784/254) is modified
>    >     (a sufficiently different, on-topic version of the same question):
>    >     it's different/better because in particular it identifies a problem to
>    >     be solved, and it asks for advice (on how to deal with this problem).
>
>    The site's format and strategy is not designed for long discussions.
>      Its strategy is to serve for Q+A (answering questions) now, and for
>      previously answered questions to remain in a clean format which works
>      well for reference (so that future readers who find the topic using a
>      search engine can read simple Q+A).
>
>    If people wanted long unfocused discussions, an option would be to
>      use of a 'Chat' room.

Is it nevertheless a good question?

Is it likely to help readers? Likely to harm the site?

Should we close the question, keep it open, wait to see whether the question is up- or down-voted, allow it (exceptionally) once?

I'm not sure what the historical reason is for closing "polling" questions on Stack Exchange, beyond a general feeling that "this isn't the kind of **personal** question that we ask here." Maybe it comes from the Help's [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) which includes,

> To prevent your question from being flagged and possibly removed, avoid asking subjective questions where …
>
> 1. every answer is equally valid: “What’s your favorite ______?”

Answer (score 1):

I think the question should be *closed* due to the already cited SE-policy, [*"What types of questions should I avoid asking?"*](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)

> To prevent your question from being flagged and possibly removed, avoid asking subjective questions where …
>
> 1. Every answer is equally valid: “What’s your favorite ______?”

Such questions/topics are better suited for the [*Chat-rooms*](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=buddhism.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 0):

Agreeing with Lanka here. It looked to me as overly broad, personal-opinion-based polling question that would lead to discussions in comments and in general would look more like a forum thread than a question with answers.

in general, we are already way more liberal than many other SE sites, we are very permissive about vague questions, reference-less answers, discussion in comments etc.

There is a reason why being liberal is appropriate in our case, but we can't stretch our policies indefinitely, and I think this case is where I'd draw the line.

Comment: Do you happen to know of any other sites (non-SE forums) where this kind of question would be allowed?

Answer (score 0):

I'm inclined to permit it, if only because people tend not to use [this site's main chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15162/buddhism) -- and so, telling people to "use chat instead" isn't necessarily helpful or possible.

But now Lanka created [a chat room for that question](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68022/discussion-on-answer-by-kauva-aatma-studying-and-practicing-buddhism) (which may or may not be deleted automatically after a while, depending on how many people use it) so I hope that's an adequate alternative.