# Essay requests and sermon invitations disguised as questions

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions, specific-question

I think the questions that sort of expect answerers to write an essay or give a sermon on a given topic without containing a clearcut question might not be ok for this site. What do you think?

Example 1: [Can someone provide explanation on dependent origination](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/24620/can-someone-provide-explanation-on-dependent-origination)

Example 2: [What happens to one in a locked in syndrome?](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/24655/what-happens-to-one-in-a-locked-in-syndrome)

Comment: Sounds right. Can you give an example?

Comment: Added the most recent examples. But I remember seeing others in the past.

Answer (score 0):

We have [Moderation policies for Questions](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1558/254) (FAQ), which allow those types of question:

> "**Too broad**": we are allowed to ask a broad question, even a question which could theoretically take a whole book to answer. The site allows (welcomes) beginner questions. You can't expect hugely long answers though, so if a question is very "broad" then an answer might be quite 'shallow': a superficial summary of the topic, and/or a reference to further reading on the topic.

"Not containing a clearcut question" is also supposed to be acceptable, per the current FAQ:

> "**Unclear what you're asking**": if possible we prefer to avoid closing 'unclear' questions, because... [etc.]

That policy is quite old and up-voted; it would be difficult to get a lot of support, from users in the Community, for changing it (though you're welcome to try).

Some users seem to dislike our closing any question ... changing the policy and/or closing questions might be considered objectionable ... maybe it's better to ignore (rather than close, and rather than discuss trying to define new policy for) these questions?

---

I think we can (currently) be expected to accept (not close) these questions, and I suppose we handle them as follows:

- Post comments asking for clarification, for example, "Do you mean X? Do you want an answer of type Y? Isn't this question difficult to answer because of reason Z?"
- Treat them as a [reference-request](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reference-request) question; for example you might not want to write an essay on dependent origination; but authors already have written on that subject, maybe the OP's question could be answered with a link to one of those essays (if you know any existing text[s] that may answer the OP's question)
- Leave it unanswered; or post just a sketch of an answer, "a superficial summary of the topic", or find out what the main/single point of the question is and just address that.

You're right that "Too broad" and "Unclear" (etc.) are among the reasons for closing a question, on other Stack Exchange sites; on this site though we decided to accept a diversity of questions.