# Should we close this question as 'too broad'?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

Should we close [this question](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/25068/254) as 'too broad'?

I thought we should not, because:

- People seem[ed] able and willing to answer it
- Our [Moderation policies for Questions](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1558/254) says that 'too broad' isn't a reason for closing
- I myself ask 'broad' questions (and appreciate the answers they get)
- I don't necessarily 'like' this kind of question so might prefer to see it posted as 1 question than as 7 questions ... if the OP posted it as 7 different questions, that might seem more 'hostile' than if it's just one question ... or it might seem like an extended argument, e.g. you answer 1 question and the OP posts 6 more questions more or less like the first. So, in a way, seeing all the questions together like that makes the question seem more finite, thus more answerable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have reopened the question. It has 7 answers so even though it might be classified as "too broad", I agree that users were able to answer it (or parts of it) and therefore can remain open.