# Questions regarding mental health

Tags: discussion

I'd appreciate your thoughts on the answers in certain threads regarding mental health, where a presumed illness of the person asking sometimes is being assessed, diagnosed, and suggested a specific buddhist practice with assumed good effects on health.

I believe the answers come from a will to help. However, i also believe that it's not exclusively a buddhist topic. I suspect this is not a new subject, but i am curious to see what your take is on this?

Coming from the clinical world, i believe there are good reasons for being cautious, for the sake of safety and health.

I would have responded directly in the topic at hand, but my reputation score prevents me from doing it.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for asking.

What do you recommend: that the question be closed? Or modified? Or answered in a certain way?

Given your reputation you could post an answer of your own, only you couldn't comment on an existing answer.

Just as it happened I have some experience with psychosis, more 2nd-hand than 1st- ... I imagine I know some of the reasons for caution.

I guess I allowed (didn't close) the question, partly because:

- This site [is more liberal](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1572/254) than most other sites, about what questions are permitted
- I'm hoping perhaps naively that users who reply will be cautious and do no harm
- "Talk to a doctor" is cautious but not the be-all and end-all of life -- the doctors I've met know medications, and something of the difficulties patients have, and about society, but ...
- The OP has obviously talked to a doctor already (and the symptoms if any appear to be intermittent, e.g. the question is lucid)
- I've read here that Buddhism (to some extent) attracts people with a mental illness, and I hope that experienced practitioners might have met this before and know how to answer to this question.

I guess another reason is that I'm conscious that a diagnosis can be a stigma, which causes other people to act weird and to exclude you from (their) society, e.g., "we can't talk about *that*... we can't talk with *you*... go somewhere else ..." -- and "coming from a will to help", as you said, I don't want to respond like that e.g. by forbidding the topic, nor e.g. the OP's access to Q+A here.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I'm not sure the alternatives is for me alone to recommend, i brought it up primarily to hear others thoughts. But since you ask, i think it's a two sided thing: 1. There will probably always be an overlap between clinical health topics and buddhist topics, and i prefer an accepting attitude towards _questions_ about it. I am more interested in the _consequences of the answers provided_. 2. Some of the specific concepts brought up makes me uncertain whether buddhism adress them at all, as they are modern concepts in a sense.

Comment: Lastly, i feel hesitant to pinpoint a specific post, but rather look at the topic in a general sense.