# We're going thru 'that phase'

Tags: discussion

I saw this on philosophy stackexchange... too many high rep users covertly believe they are experts, and any questions they can't answer are deemed bad questions; any answers they disagree with are bad answers. Fix that, or this stackexchange is finished.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps there's a difference between "can't" answer and "won't".

There are many questions I can't answer -- literally, most questions -- and I know I'm not an expert. I don't deem "any question I can't answer are bad", and I generally want to read other people's (relatively more expert) answers.

Nevertheless there may be such a thing occasionally as a relatively "bad" question.
Standard SE close reasons for example include "Needs details or clarity" (unclear), "Needs focus" (too broad), and "Opinion-based", as well as "off-topic". And on this site there are other "[policies](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1558/254)" e.g. not being hostile towards other traditions, avoiding broad comparisons.

You asked 7 questions on this site in the last 24 hours. One was downvoted. I'm not sure that is "we" who are going through a phase.