# Is there a question limit, or is moderator just browbeating me?

Tags: discussion, questions

Is there a question limit, or is moderator just browbeating me? I asked three questions this evening, in about 6 hours. I thought that would be OK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right then.

If there were a simple limit, written somewhere in the Help or the Terms of Service, then I'd point you to that -- but there isn't. So I need to give you a slightly longer answer.

If a user misbehaves somehow, moderators should and can send a formal "moderator message" -- to ask the user to stop (a moderator will normally use a simple comment to ask, first, before sending a more formal "moderator message").. There are various different messages, a dozen of them, prewritten by Stack Exchange, to use for different circumstances (i.e. different types of unwanted behaviour) -- scenarios like "excessive comments", "abusive to others", "sockpuppet upvoting", and so on.

The pre-written message which seems to best fit this scenario is:

> **consistently low quality questions over time**
>
> We're writing in reference to your Buddhism Stack Exchange account:
>
> We've noticed that you've asked many questions, a large number of
> which were not well received by other members of our community.
>
> Specifically, many of your questions were downvoted and closed because
> they seemed to be hastily written, or of the [type that we'd prefer
> users refrain from
> asking](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). This is a
> troubling pattern; we'd like to make sure that you've read the help
> that we have available for asking questions. Please take some time to
> read *all* of the information linked below prior to asking another
> question:
>
> - An overview of [how our system works](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/tour)
> - A brief [guide on how to ask questions](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)
> - A short summary of [questions we permit](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)
> - Help on [formatting your questions](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/editing-help)
>
> We recommend taking a look at highly upvoted questions within the tags
> that interest you as examples of how to ask better questions. We
> really want you to have a good experience here, and the first step to
> that is making sure that your questions are clear, on topic and
> provide all of the information someone would need to answer.

The links in that message aren't necessarily especially helpful -- not very "constructive criticism" or prescriptive, won't really help you write a good question for this site -- it is just a prewritten template available to moderators of every SE site.

Still the fact that the message exists implies to be that there is such a thing as "too many questions", or, "a question limit". Or more specifically, that the following is something which the network wants users to avoid, and expects moderators to keep a lid on somehow:

> We've noticed that you've asked many questions, a large number of
> which were not well received by other members of our community.
>
> Specifically, many of your questions were downvoted and closed because
> they seemed to be hastily written, or of the [type that we'd prefer
> users refrain from asking.

The early users of this site who helped to define the policies on Meta wanted the [Moderation policies for Questions](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1558/254) to be unusually tolerant -- and so it is, it has been, compared with other SE sites.

I don't want to complain and tell you that you ask bad questions, but it's true that I for one find your questions difficult to understand for various reasons and I can't tell why you're asking them. If they're not especially "good" (i.e. "well-received") questions, perhaps you could at least limit the rate at which you ask them (possibly also taking time to prepare them more carefully, to make them more obviously understandable and important, i.e. worth trying to ask and answer).

I've no idea how many is "too many". This is only a small SE site with little traffic, as you know, so all regular users certainly notice every question. If you post every day and if every post is a bit annoying that's perhaps too often. I imagined (personal opinion) that posting a couple of times a week isn't too  many, is easy for someone to ignore if they do find it annoying.

At this moment, 5 of the most recent 7 questions on the site are yours -- it's kind of noticeable, hard to ignore.

You have asked [300 questions](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/users/2512/satirical-buddhist?tab=questions&sort=votes) in total -- half of them have no upvotes at all.

Sorry to be brief. I don't have time to discuss this in detail but perhaps I answered your question. I'm about to be offline for several days now probably, hopefully Andrei will be able to moderate this site alone for bit.

Comment: while my questions often aren't especially iin the flavour of this site, i don't think they are a poor fit for it.

Comment: Actually there is a technical limitation by the owner implemented, limiting to 40 min a post, at least for not registered, Nyom.