# Don't ask unless Moderators don't feel disturbed a Mohayana rule?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, moderation

Moderator [Andrei Vollkov](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/41498/how-are-ingratitude-and-lack-of-awarness-of-relation-dependency-related) wrote:

> Users are advised to limit their asking activity to one question a day to avoid flooding the home page with their content.

Aside of the circumstance that Volkov is surely not given to advice even anybody, not to speak that one would hardly ask, what's the matter with goining against the page owners policy to serve personal preferences?

Using an enviroment for ones living and entertaining and activily going against it's purpose and owners wishes. Grave lack of gratitude and feeling obligated? Is that what Mohayana teaches their disciples: backyard-dictatorshipism?

Does he like to give a sample of how duty and gratitude should be understood? Secret message?

`BSE-Glosary:`

> **Off-topic** because… - each community decides which specific topics are and are not allowed on their site. You can see this list of off-topic subjects for this site by viewing this help center article.
>
> > This question does not appear to be about programming within the scope defined in the help center.
>
> If you believe the question can be reworded to fit within the scope, consider editing the question or leaving comments for improvement.

One may decide whether such is a mental, dhammic, on-topic (metta-issue) or a meta-thing and move on accordingly.

*[Note that this isn't given for stacks, exchange and other worldy trades but to escape from it]*

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because This question does not appear to be about Buddhist philosophy, teaching, and practice, within the scope defined in the help center.

Comment: I would give a moderator a thumb up anyway .. to review so many questions is not an easy with high level of Buddhism knowledge and what i know "true" Buddhist now become less and less.  i guess it's not a  paid job by the way.

Comment: Why am i seeing this? This is a meta question... Also please use a translator, this unintelligible language is not suited for public discourse imo. Perhaps if your content was intelligible you would be allowed to post more.

Comment: Moderator, seeing it's actually a meta topic, could move it there, but since actually not lokking for moderate but to domain, leaving it here to be not a serious matter.

Comment: 'Why am i seeing this?' = vipaka

Answer (score 1):

We (the moderators of this site) try to implement the policies of SE, and the specific policies of this site -- there are not specifically "Mahayana" or "Theravada" rules.

We learned these policies from SE, and from this site's community -- and we evolved and practised them over the last 6 years or so -- to handle (or more usually, to allow) various normal situations and a few less usual [edge-cases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edge_case).

I also tried to document many of the most important policies using the [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) tag.

Our policy about rate-limiting questions is one which I tried to explain here -- [Is there a question limit, or is moderator just browbeating me?](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2530/254)

I think that other SE sites don't normally define a limit based on the *quantity* of questions, but instead have policies based on *quality* -- i.e. a user can ask unlimited *high-quality* questions, but low-quality questions are closed.

The quality standard for questions on *this* site is different from SE's usual -- the standard here is almost non-existent, see the [Moderation policies for Questions](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1558/254) -- instead this site's community wanted to allow almost all questions. And so, moderators instead evolved a policy to limit the rate at which each user asks questions -- that's to avoid any single user's flooding the site's front/active page (flooding it with potentially low-quality questions).

As Andrei suggested, asking one question per day at most ought to be more enough (I think even two a week might be enough and not too many).

Also, you should probably know, some types of question aren't allowed at all:

- Questions about policies and moderation of this site -- ask those here on Meta not on the main site
- Questions (or answers or comments) intended as personal criticism or rebuke of other users -- that is not what this site is for at all, and would be edited or deleted