# What are your suggestions and vision for moderation in 2024? And opportunity to moderate BSE

Tags: discussion, moderation

Happy New Year to users of Buddhism Stack Exchange!

In this New Year, the [moderators of Buddhism SE](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) would like to get your feedback on:

1. Suggestions for improvement: What would you change on Buddhism SE, if you had the chance to do so?
2. Vision for the future: How would you like to change the direction of Buddhism SE, if you had the chance to do so?
3. Opportunity to moderate Buddhism SE: If we have new openings for moderator positions, would you be interested to volunteer to fill them?

Suggestions for improvement and vision for the future are welcome even if you're not interested to become a moderator.

On the other hand, if you are unhappy with the way things are, you can change it for the better, if you were given the opportunity to do so, instead of complaining or giving up on the status quo. Please read "[Who are the site moderators, and what is their role here?](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/help/site-moderators)".

Answer (score 1):

Some suggestions.

### Chat

Other sites have an active Chat room

- For socializing ("How are you?")
- For off-topic chat ("How's your weather?")
- For chat about the site ("What do you think of `[this question](http:\\example)`?")

I don't generally very much want to chat myself online, unfortunately, but other sites seem to.

This site's chat room is so unused that no-one uses it (if anyone tried to, no-one would notice) but maybe it's important:

- https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/chat

The existence/location/activity of the chat room is not well-advertized by the UI and I don't know what (so far as I know, there's nothing) we can do about that.

### Meta Bot

The Community bot sweeps old topics to the top of the active view, if they don't have an upvoted answer.

IMO these are by definition the least popular/useful topics.

> [image]

Perhaps moderators should delete them -- especially on the Meta site -- to avoid polluting its Active view.

### ChrisW on Meta

Historically @ChrisW has posted at length on Meta, which I find tedious.

Perhaps another moderator could be more concise, easier to read.

### Curating the main site

If you think the posts on the main site have value, you could maintain them.

For example before I started as moderator I reviewed all the posts on Meta and rationalized how they're tagged.

I never did that on the main site (a much bigger task) but you could begin to -- choose topics (e.g. chronologically or those which interest you) and edit their tags.

That would "bump" old (interesting?) topics to the top of the Active view (for current users to review), and ensure they're well-tagged (perhaps for the benefit of future users).

### Curating new question

SE wanted to be both a resource for current users (to ask questions), and for future readers (already-answered questions).

The moderation policies proposed by the early users of this site, e.g.

- [Moderation policies for Questions](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1558/254)
  ... is very non-standard.

Perhaps we should review that:

- Is "our way" working well?
- Should be change it to be more like "the SE way", closing lower quality or already-asked questions?

### Problem users

If users cause problems for other users, be stricter about suspending them.
Maybe follow the SE standard:

1. 1 week
2. 1 month
3. 1 year

We may be sympathetic and not want to suspend a user.
We may say that if other users leave because of this user then that's their fault for overreacting.
Even so perhaps we're failing as moderators and should do better.

The "Disruptive behaviour" section of [this post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/04/06/a-day-in-the-penalty-box/) is descriptive and ends with this, we can't say we weren't warned:

> and, even worse, these behaviors begin to actively turn people away from our community, stunting its growth and harming everyone.

Answer (score 1):

### Low-quality answers

Another way to increase the overall quality of the site might be to delete mediocre answers.

For example I posted [2000 answers](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/users/254/chrisw?tab=answers&sort=newest), heaven help us -- that's 68 pages, and if I order them by "Score" then those with 0 votes begin on page 51 -- so 25% of them have a score of 0 or less.

It might be good -- for the quality of the site and for the benefit of any future readers -- to delete these.

They could be deleted by the author -- or maybe someone might want to volunteer to delete other people's.